# XSLT: Maintain structure when using "value-of"

Tags: xslt

Suppose I've the following contents in a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="Fruits">
 <FRUIT>
   <TYPE> APPLE </TYPE>
   <COLOUR> RED </COLOUR>
   <SIZE> 5 </COLOUR>
 </FRUIT>
</xsl:variable>
```

I can then easily grab the properties i.e:

```
<xsl:variable name="FirstColour" select="$Fruits/FRUIT[1]/COLOUR"/>
```

But suppose I want to choose whether to use my Fruits variable or a Vegetables variable for some later condition:

```
<xsl:variable name="Food">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="GoFruit">
      <xsl:value-of select="$Fruits" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="GoVeg">
      <xsl:value-of select="$Vegetables" />
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

I can no longer access the properties of my fruit through the food var because the `"xsl:value-of"` function would have collapsed the structure, meaning I can't do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Food/FRUIT[1]/COLOUR"/>
```

Is there any way to preserve the structure (something other than "value-of")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud use a `<xsl:copy-of>` instead. This will create the structure instead evaluating the node values.

Thus you will use:

```
 <xsl:copy-of select="Fruits" />
```

and you should retrieve the fruit or vegetables structure in your output.